# Smoothing a continuous section in 1-jet bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, fibre-bundles

Here is a question I encountered when reading the book "Convex Integration Theory by D.Spring". My question lies in the second paragraph to the proof of theorem 4.2($C^{0}$-dense $h$-principle).
I state the main issue in the follows:

Let $p:X \rightarrow V$ be a smooth fibre bundle and let $\mathcal{R} \subset X^{(1)}$ be an open relation. Let $h \in \Gamma(X)$ and
$\varphi \in \Gamma(X^{(1)})$ which is a continuous extension of $h$. Suppose there is a closed set $K_{0} \subset V$ such that $h$ is $C^{1}$ over some
neighborhood of $K_{0}$ and $j^{1}h= \varphi$ on $K_{0}$.

The author attempts to reduce the proof to the case in which both $h$ and $\varphi$ is smooth over $V$ \ $K_{0}$. After the first part of the second paragraph, we indeed obtain $h,\varphi$ such that $h$ is smooth outside $K_{0}$ and $p^{1}_{0} \circ \varphi=h$ and $\varphi(V) \subset \mathcal{R}$ but at this stage $\varphi$ is only continuous. For the second part, the author says as follows:

"Again employing the bundle $p^{1}_{0}: X^{(1)} \rightarrow X$, up to a further small homotopy on $\varphi$ in $\mathcal{R}$ over the base $h(V) \subset X$ one may assume $\varphi$ is smooth on $V$ \ $K_{0}$"

I suspect the above argument is that we consider the bundle 
 $p^{1}_{0}: \iota^{*}X^{(1)} \rightarrow h(V)$, which is the pull-back bundle of $p^{1}_{0}: X^{(1)} \rightarrow X$ along the map $h(V) \hookrightarrow X$ and apply the smoothing approximation theorem to $\varphi$
in the neighbourhood $\mathcal{R} \cap \iota^{*}X^{(1)}$. But it seems like a little gap exists in this argument since $h(V)$ itself is not entirely a smooth manifold only outside $h(K_{0})$. A point is that we cannot deform $\varphi$
 over $K_{0}$ so it seems like we must approach this problem over all $h(V)$.

Can someone give me a treatment for this gap or instruct me another idea to the author's original argument? Thanks a lot!!